# Single word for program planning,attending and describing the experience

Tags: single-word-requests

When set of artists combine, plan, produce and market a program there are various terms to refer this activity. e.g Production, Staging.

When a set of friends make a plan to attend a program (say, to attend a movie/drama/watch a game), really attend that and then discuss/share things about that program, is there a single English word to describe their whole activity?

I can think of 'enjoyment', 'entertainment' etc, but I don't think they really describe the situation I describe above.

Comment: I don't believe there is a single, atomic English word which captures all those aspects of the experience, nor a short, standard phrase.

Comment: can it be *hanging out*?

Comment: do you mean sort of like "a day out"?  we planned a day out in NYC.

Comment: Agree with @DanBron. I think the closest you can come would be something like: "We soaked ourselves in a day of baseball."

Comment: It's an "event", but somewhere the event must be described.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you go to a museum with friends who are interested in contemporary painting. You spend the whole afternoon at the Paul Getty Museum and then go somewhere quiet to discuss your experience.  I would call this **"a didactical entertainment" or "a didactical experience".**

Answer (score -1):

There are social websites for this, for example see [Movies and Discussions Meetups](http://movies-and-discussions.meetup.com), is that what you mean?

Comment: Plz add reason for down-vote.